# ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [pesld103_MMap: errno 1 errmsg Opetation not permitted],

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, import, cloud

Encountering the below error:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [pesld103_MMap: errno 1 errmsg Opetation not permitted],[],[],[]...

Have changed the fstab entry to:
 tmpfs   /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults        0 0

But then too getting the same error when trying to import. Could anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Please add further more explanation so that we can understand your question.

Comment: ORA-00600 is usually *bad news* as it represents Oracle bug you should report to Oracle Support.

Comment: There is an exact hit on this issue on Oracle Support (support.oracle.com).  Doc ID 1625010.1.  I hope you have a support contract.

Comment: Does the error only happen on import, or will it also occur when you try to natively compile objects, like `alter procedure some_procedure_name compile plsql_code_type=native;`?  Also, just a wild guess, but have you restarted the database since changing fstab?

Comment: @JonHeller I had not restarted the database after changing fstab as the oracle database is on EC2 instance on AWS. I rebooted the instance and the issue was resolved. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Restart the database after changing fstab.  Oracle support document `ORA-600 [pesldl03_MMap: Errno 1 Errmsg Operation Not Permitted] (Doc ID 1625010.1)` describes the steps to change the file, but does not mention restarting the database.